# How to clear bearer tokens in Ktor-client for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I am using Ktor client for Android together with the plugin: `io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:1.6.4`. The current implementation is similar to this [snippet](https://ktor.io/docs/auth.html#bearer).

Now I want to implement a 'log out' function when after a button is clicked the tokens are deleted, the question is... how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case you are looking for the same functionality in ktor version 2.0+

```
val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
    install(Auth) {
        bearer {}
    }
}
    
client.plugin(Auth).providers.filterIsInstance<BearerAuthProvider>()
                .firstOrNull()?.clearToken()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get an instance of the `Auth` plugin, find a `BearerAuthProvider` provider and call the `clearToken` method to delete tokens. Here is an example:

```
val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
    install(Auth) {
        bearer {}
    }
}

val provider = client.feature(Auth)!!.providers.filterIsInstance<BearerAuthProvider>().first()
provider.clearToken()
```

Comment: Thank you this did exactly what I needed!

Comment: This should be mentioned in the documentation