# KTOR Client and Spring Switchuser

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ktor

I'm trying to implement a client for spring-security's `SwitchUserFilter` (server-side).  As client I'm using KTOR (with OKHttp inside).

`SwitchUserFilter` requires me to log in, then drop the `Authorization` header and use the `Cookie` tinstead.  If I send the `Authorization` header together with the `Cookie` header, spring's SecurityContext coming from `SwitchUserFilter` will be overwritten with my admin user again.

Is there something I can configure in KTOR, so that the [Authorization] header is removed, once I have switched the user?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991824/how-to-clear-bearer-tokens-in-ktor-client-for-android?rq=1

Comment: Alsmost, I did `client.feature(Auth)!!.providers.removeAll { true }` (since I only have the BasicAuth provider there, that worked). Thanks!
Do you want to put this in the answer? The solution is similar, but the question is different, so I think its worth it.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

KTOR has to be setup with two things:

1. SwitchUserFilter will send a redirect (HTTP 302) that we need to ignore.  For this a HttpResponseValidator needs to be configured.
2. Auth needs to be removed similar to the comment from @Delta_George

   ```
   HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    HttpResponseValidator {
        // for 302 don't react - so we can switch user successfully. If we follow, this doesn't work anymore.
        validateResponse { response ->
            val statusCode = response.status.value
            val originCall = response.call
            if (statusCode < 300 || originCall.attributes.contains(ValidateMark)) {
                return@validateResponse
            }

            val exceptionCall = originCall.save().apply {
                attributes.put(ValidateMark, Unit)
            }
            val excResp = exceptionCall.response
            val excRespTxt = excResp.readText()
            when (statusCode) {
                302 -> {} // do nothing on "Found" statuscode
                in 300..399 -> throw RedirectResponseException(excResp, excRespTxt)
                in 400..499 -> throw ClientRequestException(excResp, excRespTxt)
                in 500..599 -> throw ServerResponseException(excResp, excRespTxt)
                else -> throw ResponseException(excResp, excRespTxt)
            }
        }
    }
    ... // other configurations
   }
   ```

and `impersonate(...)`:

```
    suspend fun impersonate(impersonateWithUser: PersonEntity): Impersonation<PersonEntity> {
        return runCatching {
                val toImpersonate = impersonateWithUser.login.replace(Regex("^\\+"), "%2B")
                client.get<HttpResponse>("$BASE_URL/login/impersonate?username=${toImpersonate}") // with baseauth again
            }.map {
                when (it.status) {
                    HttpStatusCode.Found -> {
                        client.feature(Auth)!!.providers.removeAll { true }
                        Impersonation.ok(impersonateWithUser)
                    }
                    else -> Impersonation.failure(impersonateWithUser, it)
                }
            }.getOrElse {
                Log.e(TAG, "impersonate: ", it)
                Impersonation.communicationError(impersonateWithUser, it)
            }
    }
```

to end the impersonation you call the respective endpoint given in SwitchUserFilter on the serverside.